# How to set variables of the client GameObject in the NetworkManager (Unity C#)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking

So I'm experimenting with the NetworkManager components in Unity, and I'm trying to make a multiplayer hide and seek game. I want the manager to assign each client's GameObject an int that tells if they're a client or the host (which I can then work with). I also want it to do the same with the spawn points, to distinguish spawn points for hiders from spawn points for seekers.

Please forgive me if there is an easy answer to this, but how would one go about doing something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Network.isServer to check this.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Network-isServer.html 
You can assign int or Vector3 values to gameobjects and sync them across network using SyncVar.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.SyncVarAttribute.html

Comment: So even if a player is running as a host and not a direct server Network.isServer will still return true?

Comment: As far as I know, Yes. Still, I would recommend you to test it out.